# Can we force the compiler to use a specific register to use as a variable?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, calling-convention

I need to use a register, specifically `ebx` as variable argument passing(kinda like those BIOS function selectors in AX). How can I use it in C? I tried `volatile register int r0 asm("ebx");`. It does work when I compile with flag `-std=gnu99`.

Is there a method that is valid in actual C99? Is there any problem to use gnu99? It does store the variable in register `ebx` when written in `r0` in C. Also, as I know the term `volatile` tells the compiler that the variable may change outside the program. Is the above declaration correct in that sense?

Comment: The C standard is described in reference to an abstract machine and has no concept of actual machine registers, so any such feature is necessarily compiler-specific.

Comment: Are you talking about using that `r0` declaration at *global* scope?  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html.  I don't think you need `volatile` for that; function boundaries already imply that global variables can change because any function can reference them.  But if you mean register local vars, no, they're not guaranteed to work for *anything* except making an `"r"` constraint pick that register for an Extended Asm statement. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html (gcc does keep the var in that register most of the time, unlike clang.)

Comment: Also, normal function calling conventions do pass args in registers, although none of the ones GCC knows about use EBX.  e.g. `__attribute__((regparm(3)))` in 32-bit mode will pass the first up to 3 integer/pointer args in eax, edx, and ecx. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html.  64-bit code, and code for most non-x86 ISAs, already uses good register-arg calling conventions by default.  But it's not easy to get GCC to use different calling conventions without modifying its config files and rebuilding the compiler from GCC sources.

Comment: @PeterCordes r0 is in global scope.

Comment: Ok, well tying up a register globally just so you can use it for arg-passing in a few functions doesn't sound efficient.  If you want register args globally, use `-mregparm=3`. (except for library function calls, unless you recompile libc as well)